# Сделать функцию, которая заполнит переданный двумерный массив состоящий из целых чисел по шаблону

Tags: java

Шаблон: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не особо понимаю как это можно реализовать , да и как она строится тоже. Извините за кривую картинку.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, имеется массив `array`, в котором `n` строк и `m` столбцов, а также есть счетчик `k`.

Заполняем каждую четную (`i % 2 == 0`) строку:

```java
array[i][j] = k++;
```

Заполняем каждую нечетную строку (`i % 2 == 1`) в обратном порядке:

```java
array[i][m - j - 1] = k++;
```

То есть заполнение массива можно реализовать примерно следующим образом:

```java
private void fill(int[][] array, int n, int m) {
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            int jj = i % 2 == 0 ? j : m - j - 1;
            array[i][jj] = k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть два варианта решения для заполнения прямоугольного массива с размерностью `r x n` (`r` - количество строк, `c` - количество столбцов) числами в диапазоне `v ∈ [0 .. r * c - 1]`:

1. Идти от "конца" массива `arr[r - 1][c - 1]` к началу `arr[0][0]` с инкрементом `v`
2. Идти от "начала" массива `arr[0][0]` к концу `arr[r - 1][c - 1]` с декрементом `v`

Для нечётного числа столбцов выбор направления неважен, а для чётного результаты будут отличаться.

Прохождение по массиву выполняется при помощи обычного вложенного цикла, но
с учётом "вертикальности" змейки, внешний цикл проходит по столбцам, а внутренний -- по строкам.  Индекс строки будет "переворачиваться" для каждого второго столбца.

- Вариант 1:

```java
public static void fillInc(int[][] arr) {
    int v = 0;
    int r = arr.length;
    int c = arr[0].length;
    boolean d = true;
    
    for (int i = c; i-- > 0; ) {
        for (int j = r; j-- > 0; ) {
            int jj = d ? j : r - j - 1;
            arr[jj][i] = v++;
        }
        d = !d;
    }
}
```

- Вариант 2:

```java
public static void fillDec(int[][] arr) {
    int r = arr.length;
    int c = arr[0].length;
    int v = r * c - 1;
    boolean d = true;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            int jj = d ? j : r - j - 1;
            arr[jj][i] = v--;
        }
        d = !d;
    }
}
```

Тесты:

```
int[][] arr = new int[4][7];
fillInc(arr);
print(arr);

arr = new int[5][6];
fillInc(arr);
print(arr);

arr = new int[5][6];
fillDec(arr);
print(arr);
```

Результаты

```
[27, 20, 19, 12, 11, 4, 3]
[26, 21, 18, 13, 10, 5, 2]
[25, 22, 17, 14, 9, 6, 1]
[24, 23, 16, 15, 8, 7, 0]

----------

[25, 24, 15, 14, 5, 4]
[26, 23, 16, 13, 6, 3]
[27, 22, 17, 12, 7, 2]
[28, 21, 18, 11, 8, 1]
[29, 20, 19, 10, 9, 0]

----------

[29, 20, 19, 10, 9, 0]
[28, 21, 18, 11, 8, 1]
[27, 22, 17, 12, 7, 2]
[26, 23, 16, 13, 6, 3]
[25, 24, 15, 14, 5, 4]

----------
```

[Ответ на похожий вопрос про "змейку" в квадратном массиве](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1440629/386633)